# Ajax star rating problem

Tags: php, ajax, plugins, cakephp-1.3

I am implementing ajax star rating plugin which is given in the bakery article [here is link](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/schneimi/2010/08/19/ajax-star-rating-plugin-1) . I followed the steps given in the article but only the stars are getting displayed but we can't vote it and also mouse over messages are also not getting displayed.  I have included

$javascript->link('jquery-1.3.2.min.js');
   $javascript->link('/rating/js/rating_jquery_min.js'); 
 in my layout file (default.ctp) and have added the following code in my ctp file

$this->element('rating', array('plugin' => 'rating', 'model' => 'Product', 'id' => 148)); 
 here m applying the rating for product model, id is hard coded which is existing id for given product. 
how can i resolve this? 
Through firebug i found the following error:
$ is not defined
ratingInit() in rating_prototype.js (line 34)
()index (line 31)
[Break On This Error] $(element + '_' + i).observe('mouseover', function(e) {

Thanks
Pushpa

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the code you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Firebug (or similar) to see what file the browser is trying to load. Compare it with the actual file name and location of the image, and you'll probably see what the issue is.

My guess is it's likely to be a path issue - maybe you forgot to add the leading slash to the image filename, or something like that. But without seeing your code, that's just a guess.

Comment: Thanks Spudley, I have made some changes in the code, now the stars are getting displayed but i can't vote. even mouseover messages are not displaying.

Comment: @pushpa - well I'm glad you got the first part sorted. But you're going to have to show us some code to get any more help. At the very least, please tell us what you're seeing in Firebug as per my answer, and how it compares with what you were expecting to see.

Comment: Thanks,    I have included                                <?php echo $javascript->link('jquery-1.3.2.min.js');
echo $javascript->link('/rating/js/rating_jquery_min.js'); ?> in my layout file (default.ctp) and have added the following code in my ctp file <?php
echo $this->element('rating', array('plugin' => 'rating',
                                    'model' => 'Product',
                                    'id' => 148));
?>  here m applying the rating for product model, id is hard coded which is existing id for given product.

Comment: @pushpa - that's great. but if the stars are showing then we can be fairly sure that the JS includes are working okay. I'd still say it sounds like a path issue. Show us the URL that it's trying to load that gets 404, and show us the URL that it should be going to. Also, I suggest showing these things by editing it into your original question rather than posting comments here, because that way you'll be getting more people to help you rather than just me (also comments are harder to read than if it's in the main question text).

Comment: I got the answer, i missed Protype.js file in my layout.